# Add properties to JSON at position according to order defined in "template"

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

in order to represent my order I'm using an interface. That's not obligatory.

```
interface myOrder {
  one?: number;
  two?: number;
  three?: number;
  four?: number;
}

// start
let obj: myOrder = {"two": 2}
// add property "one".
obj.one = 1337; // evals: {"two":2, "one":1337}
// desired result {"one":1337, "two":2}
obj.four = 4;
obj.three= 3; // evals: {"two":2, "one":1337, "four": 4, "three": 3}
//{"one":1337, "two":2, "three": 3, "four": 4}
```

So what is the most **neat/elegant/general** way to let object properties (when prominent) always follow/obey a specific order?

Comment: There is no way to do that; the ordering is determined according to rules set by the JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Object properties are (generally speaking) *unordered*. Why does the order matter?

Comment: @deceze I want to output/ save a configuration as JSON and therefore would like to have a "dedicated order" in order to keep things a little more "visually consistent".

Comment: That would need to be implemented at the level of the JSON serialiser.

Comment: do you have any recourse recommendation @deceze ? Because these json-nodes will be added on the fly at runtime. I'm asking my question because I want to avoid prepopulating the whole thing with `''`.

Comment: I'd look for any library that implements a JSON serialiser that allows you to (manually) order object properties…

Comment: You should perhaps have another field which contains a list of property names in the required order if you wish this detail to be persisted across serialisation/deserialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have so much experience with typescript, but with plain js you need create a new object with the required order, an important step is check if there are some undefined value and remove them

```
interface myOrder {
  one?: number;
  two?: number;
  three?: number;
  four?: number;
}
let obj: myOrder = {"two": 2}
// add property "one".
obj.one = 1337; // evals: {"two":2, "one":1337}
// desired result {"one":1337, "two":2}
obj.four = 4;

let format = ({one,two,three,four}: myOrder) : myOrder => {
   let result = { one,two,three,four }
   Object.keys(result).forEach(key => result[key] === undefined ? delete result[key] : '');
   return result
}

console.log(format(obj))
// returns  { one: 1337, two: 2, four: 4 }
```

Comment: looks cool from first look. Ill have a closer look at it tomorrow :-)

Comment: @AndreElrico if works for you can you accept the answer as a solution?...thank you